# Missing argument for parameter 'responder' in call swift

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors, xcode6, protocols

Ok so Im going a little crazy here trying to understand where is the problem with my code. Im trying to make separate classes communicate so I could handle UI elements during file download progression.

I went for a protocol solution that seems to fit my needs perfectly:

**the protocol:**

```
protocol DownloadResponder : class {
    func downloadFinished()
}
```

**the download class:**
(for the sake of the question I only display the `download_zip` func and the `didFinishDownloadingToURL` delegate)

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

typealias CompleteHandlerBlock = () -> ()

class fileDownloader: NSObject, NSURLSessionDelegate, NSURLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    //responder
    var responder : DownloadResponder?

    init(responder : DownloadResponder) {
        self.responder = responder
    }

    var session: NSURLSession!
    var handlerQueue: [String : CompleteHandlerBlock]!

//    class var sharedInstance: fileDownloader {
//        struct Static {
//            static var instance : fileDownloader?
//            static var token : dispatch_once_t = 0
//        }
//        
//        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
//            Static.instance = fileDownloader()
//            Static.instance!.handlerQueue = [String : CompleteHandlerBlock]()
//        }
//        
//        return Static.instance!
//    }

    func download_zip(sURL: String, destination:String, name:String, fileis:Int) {

        var session:NSURLSessionTask!
        var sessionConfiguration:NSURLSessionConfiguration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("com.visi")
        sessionConfiguration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 5

        self.session = NSURLSession(configuration: sessionConfiguration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        var url = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: sURL)!)
        var downloadTask:NSURLSessionDownloadTask = self.session.downloadTaskWithRequest(url)

        downloadTask.resume()
    }

    func URLSession(session: NSURLSession, downloadTask: NSURLSessionDownloadTask, didFinishDownloadingToURL location: NSURL) {
        println("session \(session) has finished the download task \(downloadTask) of URL \(location).")

        responder?.downloadFinished()
    }
```

**the downloadFinished func in my FileInfo ViewController**:

```
func downloadFinished() {
        downloadLbl.text = "Downloaded"
        println("DOWNLOAD OVER")
    }
```

and finally, the function in my **FileInfo ViewController**:

```
func downloadFile(sender:UIButton!)
    {
     // some code...   

     fileDownloader().download_zip(datastring, destination: path, name: naming, fileis: self.fileId)
    }
```

this func call `fileDownloader().download_zip(datastring, destination: path, name: naming, fileis: self.fileId)` in my view controller triggers an error I didn't have before I add the protocol. It says: `Missing argument for parameter 'responder' in call`.
I can't think of any solution so if someone knows what it is please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `init` method of `fileDownloader` you are expecting a parameter `responder: DownloadResponder` which you are not providing when you are initializing the `fileDownloader` in the `downloadFile` method.

So instead of:

```
fileDownloader().download_zip(...
```

Do:

```
fileDownloader(DownloadResponderImplementation()).download_zip(...
```

This assumes you to also Implement the DownloadResponder protocol as for example:

```
class DownloadResponderImplementation: DownloadResponder {
   func downloadFinished() {
      //Do something here
   }
}
```

Comment: can you explain? It not something Im used to

Comment: ok, but I tried this. It returns an error too... the error is the following: 'DownloadResponder' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers. I did something wrong? the code is as shown in my question.

Comment: Well, DownloadResponder is a protocol, so you need to create a class that implements the DownloadResponder protocol and pass that in as responder for the fileDownloader.

Comment: Im not sure I understand. I did create a class with my DownloadResponder protocol (which I described above), then I pass the protocal to my viewController class so... what did I miss there?

Comment: If the FileInfo ViewController implements the DownloadResponder protocol, you can call fileDownloader(self) in the downloadFile function